# plone 4 navigation portlet does not hide

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

On plone 4.3.3 under ubuntu 14.04, whether I hide or delete the Navigation portlet, it remains visible as a horizontal bar of links just above the breadcrumbs.  This happens even when I hide or delete the Navigation portlet of both the Home folder and of its default view.  How can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: the navigation bar is not a portlet but a viewlet; follow @ulrich-schwarz advice to hide it.

Comment: Maybe you want to paste a screenshot or the relevant markup, to make clearer which element you are refering to. There might be a misunderstanding, nav-portlet is usually not above the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 4):

If you want that bar to go away unconditionally, the easiest way is to hide the viewlet that displays it:

- navigate to `http://(yourplonesite)/@@manage-viewlets`, which shows you parts you can enable and disable separately.
- Find the the bar, usually called `plone.global_sections` in ViewletManager `plone.portaltop`, and click "hide".

Answer (score 0):

Check this document:

- http://www.contentmanagementsoftware.info/plone-book/navigation/index_html

It is a for Plone 2.5, but if I understood your question correctly the answer is there.

I think you want to hide what in the document is called "navigation tabs" (rectangle with red border number 1).
In this case go to "Site setup" and uncheck "Authomatically generate tabs".

Hope I got your question right, ciao!